# Connecting Visual Studio 2010 to Oracle

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle

What is the easiest way to connect Visual Studio 2010 to an Oracle database not hosted on my local machine. Can anyone please link me to a tutorial that will help me do this as I have only ever connected using VB6 and ODBC. Or please provide me the steps involved in connecting Visual Studio 2010 to Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is probably to use [ODP.net](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) which is Oracle's official library to connect to Oracle databases (tutorials available on the linked web site)

Comment: I have been looking at this, As far as I can tell you have to install ODP.NET, set the TNS environment variable, edit the tnsnames.ora file with the server information and connect using Visual Studio. Am i going in the right direction?

Comment: @Sowmya Yup, there's even a quicker way if you use EZConnect http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/EZCONNECT you won't even have to set the tns and to create tnsnames.ora

Comment: Ok i've changed the Net Manager to make EZConnect the default method as opposed to tns. How would I go about connecting from Visual Studio 2010 now? Where would I enter all the server information and databse username and password, i mean.

Comment: Use the server explorer to navigate through the accessible databases or create an application and put the connection string in the config file (app.config or web.config)